# Float Left and RIght on inside Li Tag with seperate anchor each

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a container, where I want to display some items on left and want to put a Cart icon on right side. I tried this, but not working, whats wrong here?

Both Text and Image have separate links.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/MTHuP/)

### HTML

```
<div class="showcase">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <h1><a href="#">Item 1 + Star 1
                    <small>
                        <del>Rs. 6000</del>
                        <span> Rs. 3000</span>
                    </small>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <span class="pic"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iicon/512/buy-Cart-48.png" alt=""></a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <h1><a href="#">Item 2 + Star One
                    <small>
                        <del>Rs. 6000</del>
                        <span> Rs. 3000</span>
                    </small>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <span class="pic"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iicon/512/buy-Cart-48.png" alt=""></a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.showcase ul {list-style-type: none;padding: 0;margin: 0 5px;}
.showcase li.item {border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
.showcase li.item a {display: block;color:#000;clear:both;}
.showcase li.item span.pic img {float: right;width:50px;height:50px;float:right;}

.showcase li.item h1 {text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'fauna_oneregular' serif;white-space: normal;font-size: 0.8em;}
.showcase li.item h1 a {color:#000 !important;text-decoration: none}
.showcase li.item h1 small {color:#a51c10;display: block;}
.showcase li.item h1 small span {color:#79a510;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MTHuP/2/)

First off you need to add a clear after your floated elements to resume the document flow:

`<div style='clear:both;'></div>`

Then you need to move `float:right;` from `.showcase li.item span.pic img` into:

```
span.pic{
    float:right;
}
```

Note that this is the basic premise, you should either aim to use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) or remove the `inline` clear style for your finished code.

See this [FIDDLE with clearfix](http://jsfiddle.net/MTHuP/5/) implemented.

Answer (score 1):

1)The `<h1>` and `<a>` tag are block level elements , hence they occupy the full width, so, give inline-block

CSS:

```
.showcase li.item a {display:inline-block;color:#000;clear:both;}
.showcase li.item h1 {display:inline-block;}
```

2) You have given `float:right` for the `img` tag inside the `span`, so it floats right inside the span and not for your li, so you need to give float right for the span tag

CSS:

```
.showcase li.item span.pic{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your href link has `display:block`

Change `display:inline-block` to pic, h1 and href link

check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/MTHuP/3/

Comment: I checked, the fiddle, I wanted that Cart to be on Right Side,Extpro's Answer completely resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html and css you need to move the span tab above the a tag. check the fiddle here

```
<li class="item">
<h1><span class="pic"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iicon/512/buy-Cart-48.png" alt=""></a></span>
  <a href="#">Aaryogyam 1.7A One + One
    <small>
    <del>Rs. 6000</del>
    <span> Rs. 3000</span>
    </small></a>
 </h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MTHuP/4/